# Can the gradient of rounding operation be calculated?

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning, integer-programming

I want to integrate a rounding operation in one of my optimization problem. Since in the rest parts of my algorithm, the gradient (or subgradient) can be easily calculated (basically neural network). Now I want to add the integer constraints on the output of the algorithm, is there anyway I can do that even without the rounding operation? I don't mean to post process my output with rounding operation, I simply want to integrate the rounding operation in the whole back-propagation setting.

Comment: Rounding has a finite range, hence the gradient is always a.e. zero.

Comment: you might want to use an approximate round function that is differentiable; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951957/differentiable-approximation-of-the-round-matlab-function